# Regex for password verification

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I want to validate password .The following are my requirements.

Minimum password length:  8
Minimum number of lower case characters:  1
Minimum number of upper case characters:  1
Minimum number of numeric characters:  1

How to write a regex for this ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a function ValidatePassword instead. You may need to update this to include (For example) the password cannot contain the username.  Just a thought. :)

Comment: Regex is not the best tool for this job.

Comment: @Jacob: Usually requests like these come about when a person is using some framework that only allows a regex for validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$
```

Comment: I thought `?=` (zero-width positive look-ahead) wasn't supported in some of the common client-side languages, but after some research, I'm pleased to see I was wrong. This is the Regex to use.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Russell, a function is a better choice for password validation. And it's hard to imagine a single Regex handling all these cases. I think you would have to check each one in turn.

Individually, the Regex expressions are:

- `.{8}` matches at least 8 characters
- `[a-z]` matches a single lowercase character
- `[A-Z]` matches a single uppercase character
- `[0-9]` matches a digit

That having been said, these would only be useful for client-side checking prior to having the server do in-depth validation.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below regex for your requirements:

```
(?=^.{8}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```